# Google Dataflow / Apache Beam Python - Side-Input from PCollection kills performance

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We are running logfile parsing jobs in google dataflow using the Python SDK. Data is spread over several 100s of daily logs, which we read via file-pattern from Cloud Storage. Data volume for all files is about 5-8 GB (gz files) with 50-80 million lines in total.

```
loglines = p | ReadFromText('gs://logfile-location/logs*-20180101')
```

In addition, we have a simple (small) mapping csv, that maps logfile-entries to human readable text. Has about 400 lines, 5 kb size.

For Example a logfile entry with [param=testing2] should be mapped to "Customer requested 14day free product trial" in the final output.

We do this in a simple beam.Map with sideinput, like so:

```
customerActions = loglines | beam.Map(map_logentries,mappingTable)
```

where map_logentries is the mapping function and mappingTable is said mapping table.

However, this only works if we read the mapping table in native python via open() / read(). If we do the same utilising the beam pipeline via ReadFromText() and pass the resulting PCollection as side-input to the Map, like so:

```
mappingTable = p | ReadFromText('gs://side-inputs/category-mapping.csv')    
customerActions = loglines | beam.Map(map_logentries,beam.pvalue.AsIter(mappingTable))
```

performance breaks down completely to about 2-3 items per Second.

Now, my questions:

1. Why would performance break so badly, what is wrong with passing a
   PCollection as side-input?
2. If it is maybe not recommended to use
   PCollections as side-input, how is one supposed to build such as
   pipeline that needs mappings that can/should not be hard coded into
   the mapping function?

For us, the mapping does change frequently and I need to find a way to have "normal" users provide it. The idea was to have the mapping csv available in Cloud Storage, and simply incorporate it into the Pipeline via ReadFromText(). Reading it locally involves providing the mapping to the workers, so only the tech-team can do this.

I am aware that there are caching issues with side-input, but surely this should not apply to a 5kb input.

All code above is pseudo code to explain the problem. Any ideas and thoughts on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show the code of map_logentries?

Comment: Do you observe the same behaviour (poor performance) when using AsList() in side input?

Comment: @MarcinZablocki:

Just tried with AsList(), and it runs as fast as with our workaround. Thanks for this! Any explanation / idea on why AsList() is so much better than AsIter() or AsDict()?

Comment: I've posted my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For more efficient side inputs (with small to medium size) you can utilize

`beam.pvalue.AsList(mappingTable)`

since `AsList` causes Beam to materialize the data, so you're sure that you will get in-memory list for that pcollection.

> Intended for use in side-argument specification---the same places
>   where   AsSingleton and AsIter are used, but forces materialization of
>   this   PCollection as a list.
>
> Source: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.pvalue.html?highlight=aslist#apache_beam.pvalue.AsList

Comment: Thank you - this solves my problem and explains the reasons behind it.

Comment: Why does materializing the PCollection makes such a big performance difference? Even a non-materialized PCollection would be buffered as it is read from disk, so the issue is not with reading efficiency. Perhaps the problem is that it is read over and over again, once for each batch received by the `beam.Map`? If so, is this non-caching behavior prescribed by the API, or is it an implementation detail?

Answer (score 3):

1. The code looks fine. However, since `mappingTable` is a mapping, wouldn't `beam.pvalue.AsDict` be more appropriate for your use case?
2. Your `mappingTable` is small enough so side input is a good use case here.
   Given that `mappingTable` is also static, you can load it from GCS in `start_bundle` function of your `DoFn`. See the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43958372/large-numpy-matrix-as-dataflow-side-input?rq=1) post for more details. If `mappingTable` becomes very large in future, you can also consider converting your `map_logentries` and `mappingTable` into `PCollection` of key-value pairs and join them using [`CoGroupByKey`](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#cogroupbykey).

Comment: You are right, `AsDict()` is more appropriate here but does not change anything performancewise. I will have a deeper look at the Post you linked and try this out, it seems this could be a solution (re-using the `mappingTable`). I'll post my results here.

Comment: OK, this basically does what we are doing now as a workaround - loading the data outside of the pipeline and and re-using it in the global scope. Only difference is reading it from GCS using the GCS API, which is a good approach if we stick to this solution. However, I think using the pipeline itself for this would be the more natural way to do it.

Comment: Have you tried joining `mappingTable` with `map_logentries` with CoGroupByKey? It might be an overkill but it lets you keep `ReadFromText('gs://side-inputs/category-mapping.csv')`.

Comment: This would not work in my case, as the key (on which we perform the mapping) can actually appear multiple times (different keys of course) in a line. So I would have to multiply the 70 million lines to re-key them and later kind of "collapse" this again. Marcin Zablocki pointed to the right direction: using AsList() works perfectly well, I just dont understand why AsDict() or AsIter() dont.

Comment: @JiayuanMa I have nearly the same problem here. Only difference being that the side iinput mapping I want to pass every worker is about 1GB (mapping of IP addresses to geoLocation info). I can't simple use the join since my main collection has 4 levels of nesting that needs this ip->info translation to happen. What would you suggest for this? is the start_bundle still a good position for it? Should I use a PCollection as side input and pass it with AsDict?

Comment: @SpiXel I have limited experience with python beam SDK. Both start_bundle are side_input should be viable solutions in Java. However, start_bundle may be called several times especially for streaming pipelines. If data loading you're trying to do is slow, it will impact your performance.