# Apache Beam Java- Spark Runner - Side Input slowing down performance

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to do a lookup operation in apache beam and sending the lookup-data as side input and it is slowing my job down. I am doing the lookup operation on each row of a csv file on a particular column and passing the lookup map as side input. I am using spark as my runner. My job takes initial 3 minutes just to distribute the side inputs. The lookup-data is around 170 MB which doesn't seem much. My implementation looks like

```
Map<String, Map<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>> hm = \\getting data from external source
LookUpData lookUpData = new LookUpData(hm);       \\Simple data class which implements serializable

PCollectionView<LookUpData> filedata = pipeline.apply("create side input", Create.of(lookUpData)).apply(View.asSingleton());
```

This PCollectionView was later passed as side input.

After reading this post [Google Dataflow / Apache Beam Python - Side-Input from PCollection kills performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48242320/google-dataflow-apache-beam-python-side-input-from-pcollection-kills-perform). Tried implementing in similar way in java which looks like

```
PCollectionView<Map<String, Map<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>>> fileData = pipeline.apply("create side input", Create.of(hm)).apply(View.asMap());
```

I am getting the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to infer a coder and no Coder was specified. Please set a coder by invoking Create.withCoder() explicitly or a schema by invoking Create.withSchema()
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create$Values.expand(Create. java: 358)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create$Values.expand(Create. java: 272)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline. applyInternal(Pipeline. java:542)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.Pipeline.applyTransform(Pipeline. java: 493)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.values.PBegin. apply(PBegin. java: 56)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.Pipeline.apply(Pipeline. java:186)
at com.hsbc.eod.rule.processor.pipeline.RuleProcessorPipeline.run(RuleProcessorPipeline. java: 108)
at com.hsbc.eod.rule.processor.Main.main(Main.java:61)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Unable to provide a Coder for java.util.HashMap$Node.
Building a Coder using a registered CoderProvider failed.
See suppressed exceptions for detailed failures.
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromFactories(CoderRegistry. java: 690)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromTypeDescriptor(CoderRegistry. java:619)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoder(CoderRegistry. java: 251)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoder(CoderRegistry. java: 242)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create. inferCoderFromObject (Create. java: 808)
at org.apache. beam. sdk. transforms .Create.inferCoderFromObjects(Create. java: 740}
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create. inferCoderFromObject (Create. java: 802)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.transforms.Create.inferCoderFromObjects(Create. java: 746)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create. inferCoderFromObject (Create. java:801)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create. inferCoderFromObject (Create. java: 806)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.transforms.Create.inferCoderFromObjects(Create. java: 746)
at org.apache. beam. sdk.transforms.Create.getDefaultCreateCoder(Create. java: 728)
at org.apache.beam. sdk. transforms .Create.access$300(Create. java:105)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.Create$Values.expand(Create. java: 354)
Suppressed: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: java.util.HashMap$Node is not one of the common types.
at org.apache. beam. sdk.coders.CoderRegistry$CommonTypes.coderFor(CoderRegistry. java:151)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromFactories(CoderRegistry. java:674)
Suppressed: org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CannotProvideCoderException: Class java.util.HashMap$Node does not have a @DefaultCoder annotation.
at org.apache. beam. sdk.coders.DefaultCoder$DefaultCoderProviderRegistrar$DefaultCoderProvider.coderFor(DefaultCoder. java:89)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.CoderRegistry.getCoderFromFactories(CoderRegistry. java:674)
```

I tried implementing using `withCoder(KVCoder.of(.....))` but getting error for nested map. If this is not the correct way to implement side inputs then can someone tell me the correct way so that the initial 3 minute time is reduced.

Just to add I also see increased GC time (in red) on spark history server.

Comment: Is there another way to represent your data than `Map<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>`? I'm not sure what's going on here, but it seems to be getting confused with the nested maps. You could also consider writing your data out to a file and then reading it in rather than materializing it as part of your pipelines.

Comment: Hi @robertwb I am not sure if there is something that I can use to replace `Map<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>` as that data consist of varying number of keys and values. If I write the data in file then I won't be able to distribute the data to various spark nodes. Need my data as side input to DoFn for lookup purpose. To make use of spark's broadcast variables I have used apache beam's side input.

Comment: What if it was a `List<List<KV<String, String>>, List<KV<String, String>>>`? Just trying to figure out if it's something odd with Map, or something about side inputs.

Comment: @robertwb I could try that can you tell me what coders will i have to set for them?

Comment: You should be able to use ListCoder and KVCoder.